# relayjs: Attempted to add an ID already in GraphQLSegment:

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I have a react/relay app with the following fragment in my App.js file:

```
export default Relay.createContainer(App, {
    fragments: {
        viewer: () => Relay.QL`
            fragment on User {
                accounts(first: 10) {
                    edges {
                        node {
                            id,
                            name,
                            sfid,
                            classrooms(first:10) {
                                edges {
                                    node {
                                        id,
                                        clid,
                                        course,
                                        enrollments(first:10) {
                                            edges {
                                                node {
                                                    id,
                                                    enid
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    },
                },
            }
        `,
    },
});
```

This is the corresponding part of schema.js:

```
var userType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  description: 'A person who uses our app',
  fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField('User'),
    accounts: {
      type: accountConnection,
      description: 'A user\'s account connections',
      args: connectionArgs,
      resolve: (_, args) => connectionFromArray(getAccounts(), args),
    },
  }),
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],
});

var accountType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Account',
  description: 'A school account',
  fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField('Account'),
    name: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The name of the account',
    },
    sfid: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    classrooms: {
      type: classroomConnection,
      description: 'The classrooms at an account',
      args: connectionArgs,
      resolve: (account, args) => connectionFromArray(account.classrooms.map((classroom) => getClassroom(classroom.clid)), args)
    }
  }),
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],
});

var classroomType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Classroom',
  description: 'A classroom in a school',
  fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField('Classroom'),
    clid: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
      description: 'id of classroom in db',
      resolve: (classroom) => classroom.clid
    },
    course: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The course assigned to this classroom.'
    },
    enrollments: {
      type: enrollmentConnection,
      description: 'The students in a classroom',
      args: connectionArgs,
      resolve: (classroom, args) => connectionFromArray(classroom.enrollments.map((enrollment) => getEnrollment(enrollment.enid)), args)
    }
  }),
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],
});

var enrollmentType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Enrollment',
  description: 'A student enrolled in a classroom',
  fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField('Enrollment'),
    enid: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
      description: 'id of enrollment in db',
      resolve: (enrollment) => enrollment.enid
    }
  }),
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],
});

/**
 * Define your own connection types here
 */
var {connectionType: accountConnection} =
  connectionDefinitions({name: 'Account', nodeType: accountType});

var {connectionType: classroomConnection} =
  connectionDefinitions({name: 'Classroom', nodeType: classroomType});

var {connectionType: enrollmentConnection} =
  connectionDefinitions({name: 'Enrollment', nodeType: enrollmentType});

/**
 * This is the type that will be the root of our query,
 * and the entry point into our schema.
 */
var queryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: () => ({
    node: nodeField,
    // Add your own root fields here
    viewer: {
      type: userType,
      resolve: () => getViewer(),
    },
  }),
});
```

My database.js generates 3 accounts each with 3 classrooms and a random number of enrollments. I've triple-checked the data coming from there for accuracy, and it's fine. Some how though the `__dataID__` property for each `edge` under each `classroom` duplicates. So, instead of three classrooms the result is that each time it iterates through the map it overwrites the previous classroom with the next in the array and sends a warning: `Attempted to add an ID already in GraphQLSegment:`

Comment: did you get this issue figured out?